# Proving some basic algebraic statements using the axioms of the real numbers

Tags: real-numbers, axioms

I am trying to rigorously understand how algebra works by deriving everything from the axioms of the real numbers.  I thought this wouldn't be too difficult but it seems I don't have any idea where to start.

I assume the field axioms of the real numbers, plus the following axioms to establish total order:

1. Antisymmetry: $(a \geq b ~\wedge~b \geq a) \rightarrow a = b$
2. Transitivity: $(a \geq b ~\wedge~ b \geq c) \rightarrow a \geq c$
3. Totality: $a \geq b \vee b \geq a$

and also the following:

4. $a \geq b \rightarrow a + c \geq b + c$
5. $a \geq 0 \wedge b \geq 0 \rightarrow ab \geq 0$

Other than the completeness axiom, I assume that these are all of the axioms I need to prove any of the properties of the real numbers (Note: these all come from my understanding of the Wikipedia article, so if it is wrong please let me know).

Having this, I now want to prove the following basic identities:

6. $ a = b \rightarrow a + c = b + c$
7. $ a = b \rightarrow ac = bc$
8. $ a \geq b \wedge c \geq 0\rightarrow ac \geq bc$
9. $a \geq b \wedge b \lt 0 \rightarrow ac \leq bc$

To be honest I have no idea where to start with this.  I started working on the first by trying to prove that $ a = b \rightarrow (a \geq b ~\wedge~b \geq a)$ by somehow combining the antisymmetry and totality axiom, but failed miserably.  I thought that if I could do this, it would be an easy step to show 6. from 4.  But now that I think of it I really don't know how to do that either.   Any help at all, even a pointer in the right direction would be a start!

Answer (score 0):

1 and 4 give you 6 immediately.

7 is derived from the axioms of the product, nothing to do with order here I'd say.

8 follows from 4 and 5 ($a-b \ge 0$).

9 is very similar to the reciprocal of 5.

Comment: It seems obvious intuitively that 6 follows from 1 and 4.  But I cant seem to step through this by manipulating 1 and 4.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: $a=b \implies a \ge a = b \land b \ge b = a$ because $\ge$ is a non-strict order relationship, so $a + c \ge b + c \land b + c \ge a + c$ and then $a + c = b + c$

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm in over my head and need to break this down into simpler questions.